# How to extract various values from a complicated XML file in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I urgently need to know how to read the following XML file:

```
<uclassify xmlns="http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema" version="1.00">
<status success="true" statusCode="2000"/>
  <readCalls>
    <classify id="cls1">
      <classification>
        <class className="negative" p="0.741735"/>
        <class className="positive" p="0.258265"/>
      </classification>
    </classify>
  </readCalls>
</uclassify>
```

I need to know the following:

```
$status_code = ... (should be 2000)
$negative = ...  (the value of p, should be 0.741735)
$positive = ...  (the value of p, should be 0.258265)
```

Best regards

Andre

Comment: What have you tried? There's enough precedent for parsing XML, even in PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to extrapolate information from XML file in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183657/how-to-extrapolate-information-from-xml-file-in-php)

Comment: [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and it's [XPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) engine can easily do what you want.

Comment: OffTopic: I tried uclassify.com. It says "upset mood" (99.9%) and "negative sentiment" (98%) on a text that says windows 8 beta is presented in Barcelona ;)

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZKMV7O - I'm not adding that as an answer because I don't deserve rep for giving you the answer on a plate. *Please* look at what I did and try to understand it, *don't* just blindly use it assuming its exactly what you want - it may not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml= simplexml_load_file('temp.xml');

foreach($xml->status->attributes() as $name => $value ){
    echo $name.' '.$value.'<br>';
    }
foreach($xml->readCalls->classify->classification->children() as $node ){
    foreach($node->attributes() as $name => $value)
     echo $name.' '.$value.'<br>';
    }
```

o/p:

> success true
>   statusCode 2000
>   className negative
>   p 0.741735
>   className positive
>   p 0.258265

If you want to store them :

```
$status_code = (string)$xml->status->attributes()->statusCode;
foreach($xml->readCalls->classify->classification->class as $node ){
    ${(string) $node->attributes()->className} = (string) $node->attributes()->p;
    }
echo $status_code.' '.$positive.' '.$negative;
```

o/p:

> 2000 0.258265 0.741735